# AWS Lambda from IoT device shadow not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have a device shadow created, and I need to capture all updates on the shadow and invoke a lambda.
The values are updated in the device shadow, but the rule is not triggered.

Whenever I update the shadow, the rule is not triggered. I can see it from the chart in `Monitor \ Rules executed`.

A subscribe to the same topic in the `Test \ Subscribe to a topic` returns the information that is being sent by the device.

### Rule

**Using SQL version** `2016-03-23`

**Rule query statement** `SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'`

**Actions** Invoke a Lambda function passing the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working. 
I only changed the SQL version. For it to work it needs to be `beta`.

Found the answer in [this thread from AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244689).